# Replacing SDL with GTK+ for mouse and keyboard and displaying a frame buffer

Tags: sdl, gtk

I started building my program with SDL. I am using SDL to render a frame buffer live on the screen and also looking for user input from the keyboard and the mouse.

I have been using the following code to display a 5-6-5 RGB frame buffer on the screen.

```
SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, bitsPerPixel, SDL_SWSURFACE);
SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(frameBuffer, width, height, depth, lineWidth, Rmask, Gmask, Bmask, Amask);
SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, screen, NULL);
SDL_Flip(screen);
```

Note that Rmask, Gmask and Bmask and Amask are all 0. I am using SDL's default masking.

For the keyboard and mouse, I have been using the following code:

```
while (run) {
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type) {
        // Key is pressed
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            map<int, int>::iterator it = SDLToAndroid.find(event.key.keysym.sym);
            if (it != SDLToAndroid.end()) { /* ... */ }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            // Left click
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) { /* ... */ }
            break;
```

Where for keypresses I look them up in map to convert them to some other keys.

This works great, but I would like to use the capabilities of GTK (in terms of UI). I started including SDL into my GTK+ window using putenv environment ([The SDL_WINDOWID hack](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_GUI)) but I have two problems:

a) SDL events are not received with this solution.
b) The frame buffer display is always put on the top left of the window (0,0) but I would actually like this display to show up somewhere in the middle on my window, with some buttons above and below.

I am thinking of getting rid of SDL and just use GTK+ itself. There are a few things that I would please like to ask you, as I am very new with GTK+.

Could you please tell me what kind of GtkWidget should be used to display my frame buffer inside a window? Does anyone also please know what function I could use in GTK to perform the same task as SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom() (if it is even possible)? And finally, would you please link me to a way to get the x and y coordinates in the GtkWidget that gets clicked or moved in, and not the coordinates of the whole window, as well as keyboards input?

(I have found some solution for the mouse and keyboard. I've seen the "configure-event" used to get the x and y values, but I am not sure if this event works on any GtkWidget. Also for keyboard, what I have found is to use "activate", but I'd like to be confirmed this is the right approach.)

Comment: `GtkPixmap` is the widget I'd use; in many cases, it's backed by a `GdkPixmap` which you'd write to as an offscreen buffer and display in the widget. As for the mouse control, perhaps the Scribble tutorial can provide some insight: http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-23.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. this should be very helpful!

Comment: Side note: `GTK 3 will remove GdkPixmap and GdkBitmap. You should use cairo surfaces instead. However, because a lot of functions still use these types, they are not deprecated.` - from [the developer page](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Bitmaps-and-Pixmaps.html#gdk-Bitmaps-and-Pixmaps.description)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*`a) SDL events are not received with this solution.`*
As the page mentions, the events are not received by SDL event loop but by Gtk event loop. So you can try capturing events through Gtk event loop.

*`b) The frame buffer display is always put on the top left of the window (0,0) but I would actually like this display to show up somewhere in the middle on my window, with some buttons above and below.`*
This is possible. The hack which you are using, basically makes use of the fact that SDL (in case hardware not used directly) & Gtk are dependent on the [`Windowing system`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system) to display onto window & more precisely on [`X11`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) on most Linux desktops. Thus window creation is done by `X` which has an XID, which SDL is using from the one created for `GtkWidget`. Currently you are using `GtkWindow`'s corresponding X window, instead if you use [`GtkDrawingArea`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkDrawingArea.html)'s X window you can make the display as per your wish. Now to get the events, register callback. I tried to create a [mash up](http://pastebin.com/16XyaJh7) where on clicking "Start SDL Animation", SDL animation starts & clicking in the area of animation will trigger the `"button-release-event"` which prints the relative x & y coordinates onto the console output but key events are not being received. Hopefully you can build up on this or use it for future reference (in case).

*`Could you please tell me what kind of GtkWidget should be used to display my frame buffer inside a window?`*
You can look at [`GtkDrawingArea`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkDrawingArea.html) which is meant for custom UI interfaces or [`GtkImage`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkImage.html) with [`GdkPixbuf`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html) as few of the alternatives. You can see `gtk-demo` code or [`Cairo animation sample`](http://cairographics.org/threaded_animation_with_cairo/) to see how to proceed for your requirements.

*`Does anyone also please know what function I could use in GTK to perform the same task as SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom() (if it is even possible)?`*
For this you can have a look at [`GdkPixbuf`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/). It is possible to set raw data to `GdkPixbuf` & the pixbuf can be used to create `GtkImage` and such which you can use for displaying.

*`And finally, would you please link me to a way to get the x and y coordinates in the GtkWidget that gets clicked or moved in, and not the coordinates of the whole window, as well as keyboards input?`*
For mouse events you need to register callback for either [`"button-press-event"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) or [`"button-release-event"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-release-event). The signal callback has a [`GdkEvent`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html#GdkEvent) parameter. Typecast that in the callback to [`GdkEventButton`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventButton) & get the information which you need like relative x & y coordinates etc.
For keyboard events you need to register callback for either [`"key-press-event"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event) or [`"key-release-event"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-release-event). The signal callback has a [`GdkEvent`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html#GdkEvent) parameter. Typecast that in the callback to [`GdkEventKey`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventKey) & get the information which you need. Additionally for keyboard events the widget should be able to grab focus which you can enforce through the call [`gtk_widget_set_can_focus`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-can-focus)
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've answered all of my questions, that is amazing! Thank you so much. Thanks a lot for the code you also included, it's a great starting point for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yea I got it to work as intended! Mouse movement works, I detect key press and release, same for mouse. SDL is well integrated, I can even resize (I am doing SDL_Quit(), then init and setvideoMode again). Thanks a lot!